# Popular & Recent Weblog Entries ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

I am trying to display the most recent 15 weblog entries and the most popular 15 weblog entries in ExpressionEngine, this is my code and it gives me blank blocks, any ideas ?

```
     <div id="footseparator_05" class="foot">
   {exp:weblog:entries orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="15" disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
      <div id="footbullet_00"></div>
      <a href="{title_permalink='weblog/view'}">{title}</a>
      <div id="footseparator_06"></div>
      {/exp:weblog:entries}
    </div>
    <div id="footseparator_07"></div>
    <div id="footseparator_08" class="foot">
   {exp:weblog:entries orderby="view_count_one" sort="desc" limit="15" disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
      <div id="footbullet_01"></div>
      <a href="{title_permalink='weblog/view'}">{title}</a>
      <div id="injected_01"></div>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
    </div>
```

This code is located in one page BTW, thanks for your time :)

Comment: There could be a handful of things wrong. Setting dynamic="off" *might* be the issue, but let's start with what version of EE you're using. Is it 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `dynamic="off"` to both tags. (See the docs on this tag [here](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/modules/weblog/parameters.html#par_dynamic).)

Comment: If you're using category names in URLs, you need to specify the weblog name in the weblog:entries tag.  So try adding the weblog="weblog_name" parameter. (You can specify multiple with pipes, e.g., weblog="news|blog|articles")

Comment: D-Rock is right, just tested and confirmed that this would fix your problem.